# Why are specific NuGet dependencies not included in build output?

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, nuget

I wonder why specific NuGet packages are not included in the build output directory.

The commands I run are these:

1. `dotnet new console`
2. `dotnet add package Newtonsoft.Json -v 13.0.3`
3. `dotnet add package System.Memory -v 4.5.1`
4. `dotnet build`

After this, the output directory contains:

- My application executables and pdb
- `Newtonsoft.Json.dll`

`System.Memory.dll` is NOT included in the output directory.

For reference, my csproj file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Memory" Version="4.5.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I understand that .NET Core include a version of `System.Memory.dll`. But in this example I want to use *another* version of `System.Memory.dll` than the one shipped with .NET Core.

It does not matter which version of System.Memory I add a dependency for - it is never included in build output.

Comment: If you look inside the [System.Memory NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/#dependencies-tab) you can see it has no dll for .NET Core 2.1 and above, which will include .NET 7.0. The types that System.Memory provides must already be provided for by .NET here so there is no need for any separate .dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @MattWard:

> If you look inside the System.Memory NuGet package you can see it has no dll for .NET Core 2.1 and above, which will include .NET 7.0. The types that System.Memory provides must already be provided for by .NET here so there is no need for any separate .dll.